# XCode : Slider Object type when passed into a function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, uislider, object-type

I am trying to pass a slider object into a function and change its value

```
void sliderLoad (NSString * sliderKey, int sliderValue, id sliderOutput, id sliderSliderOutput)
{
    NSUserDefaults * sliderSavedValue = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * loadString = [sliderSavedValue objectForKey:sliderKey];
    int loadInt = loadString.intValue;
    sliderValue = loadInt;
    [sliderOutput setText:loadString];
    sliderSliderOutput.value = sliderValue;
}
```

getting errors on the last line sliderSliderOutput.value, what is the correct object type because id is wrong?

Comment: Are you using C not Objective-C?

Comment: Why are you using a C method?
Please provide the code, where you call this method, so you can get a useful answer

Comment: Im still new to Objective C, so if this is being called wrong as well maybe that is part of the issue. With the last line commented out it works fine, loads the value from the db and sets its value to the textbox (sliderOutput). what i am having trouble with is displaying this value onto the slider from within the function, it does work it i do the same line of code outside the function, but having multiple sliders, this isnt really practical.

Comment: I'm just wondering what you pass as the sliderSliderOutput parameter

Comment: a slider, haha. so its a graphic representation of the variable. this is being run in viewDidLoad, the issue is passing the slider into the function, ive tried id, UISlider and IBOutlet with no success. As i said, objective C is pretty new to me so i may be doing something stupid..

Comment: sliderLoad(@"slider1ValueKey", Slider1Vlaue, Slider1Output, Slider1SliderOutput);

Comment: *sliderLoad(key for db, slider1 variable, textbox output, slider output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `sliderSliderOutput.doubleValue = sliderValue;`
For more information, take a look at the `NSControl` Documentation.

[NSControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSControl)